# Storing values of file into array leads to weird behaviour

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, printing

Let's say I've got the file

```
5f2
3f6
2f1
```

And the code:(The printf should print the second numbers (i.e 2,6, and 1) but it doesn't

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *ptr;
    char str[100];
    char * token;
    int a, b, i;
    int arr[4];

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        ptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

   else
   {
       exit(1);
   }

   //And I'm looking to parse the numbers between the "f" so..

   while(fgets(str,100,ptr) != NULL)
   {
       token = strstr(str,"f");
       if(token != NULL)
       {
           a = atol(str); // first number
           b = atol(token+1); // second number
           arr[i] = b; // store each b value (3 of em) into this array

       }
       i++; 
       printf("Values are %d\n",arr[i]); //should print 2,6 and 1
   }
}
```

I've tried to move the printf outside the loop, but that seems to print an even weirder result, I've seen posts about storing integers from a file into an array before, however since this involves using strstr, I'm not exactly sure the procedure is the same.

Comment: `i++; 
       printf("Values are %d\n",arr[i]);` --> `i=0;...printf("Values are %d\n",arr[i++]);`  and `file` --> `ptr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i,j=0;
while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),file) != NULL)
{
   size_t n = strlen(str);
   if(n>0 && str[n-1] == '\n')
   str[n-1] = '\0';
   i = str[strlen(str)-1] - '0'; /* Convert the character to int */
   printf("%d\n",i);// Or save it to your int array arr[j++] = i;
}
```

Just move to the last character as shown and print it out as integer.

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline character you need to suppress it as shown

Comment: How would I access each element here?

Comment: @user3739406 As I have shown you can save the values in the array and later print it out or else just print out the values without storing it in array it is upto you

Answer (score 0):

You are never initializing `i`, then you are reading into `arr[i]` (which just *happens* to not crash right there), then increment `i` (to "undefined value + 1"), then print `arr[i]` -- i.e., you are writing to and reading from uninitialized memory.

Besides, your `FILE *` is `ptr`, not `file`. And you should get into the habit of using `strtol()` instead of `atol()`, because the former allows you to properly check for success (and recover from error).

Comment: Ive initialized i  to zero,and fixed the typo with the pointer, but the ouput now appears to be gigantic numbers.

Comment: @user3739406: Well, you got two out of three. Put the `i++` *after* the `printf()` (and think about the "why" while you're at it). ;-)